# SQL UPDATE (Cannot update more than 1 field)

Tags: sql

```
String sql = `"UPDATE User Set address = '" + address +"' 
and  userType  '" + userType +"' WHERE useridNric = '" + id + "'";`
```

//This is not working(2 fields).ODBC state that it has a missing operator.

`String sql = "UPDATE User Set address = '" + address +"' 
 WHERE useridNric = '" + id + "'";` //But this is working(1 field)

Hope you guys could help for the 2 fields.Been trying play with the quotes but not working

Comment: You should not use string concatenation when building sql commands. Use Parameters instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't you need an equal sign after usertype

```
String sql = "UPDATE User Set address = '" + address +"', userType = '" + userType +"' WHERE useridNric = '" + id + "'";
```

Comment: Jonathan de M.Your sql statement is right.My database is updated with the right values.Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You should replace `AND` with a comma `,` to separate field assignments, otherwise it's a syntax error (or a logical error if the assignment can be interpreted as a comparison):

```
String sql = "UPDATE User Set address = '" + address +
             "',  userType  ='" + userType +
             "' WHERE useridNric = '" + id + "'"; // <<== Rewrite with parameters
```

It goes without saying that you should be using parameterized SQL to avoid the possibility of SQL injection attacks:

```
String sql = "UPDATE User Set address = @address, userType = @userType "+
             "WHERE useridNric = @id";
```

Answer (score 0):

When updating more than one field, separate them using commas:

```
String sql = "UPDATE User Set address = '" + address +
                         "', userType ='" + userType +
           "' WHERE useridNric = '" + id + "'";
```

Comment: it state that there is a syntax error in the Update statement.Thank you for helping though

Answer (score -1):

Use `,` to delimit columns in update query as below:

```
   String sql = "UPDATE User Set address = '" + address + 
                "' , userType '" + userType + 
                 "' WHERE useridNric = '" + id + "'";
```